# How to embed youtube video on the pages

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I want to embed multiple youtube videos on pages and want to give the same option to the content creator. I did see the modules [apostrophe-oembed](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/modules/apostrophe-oembed/index.html) and [browser-apostrophe-oembed](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/modules/apostrophe-oembed/browser-apostrophe-oembed.html). Can you provide and example for the same? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is:

1. Add the widget in the app.js file. `'apostrophe-video-widgets': {},`
2. COPY the apostrophe-video-widgets folder from the node_modules folder to the root/lib/modules

Answer (score 1):

With the latest version now in November 2018, all I needed to do was to add `'apostrophe-video': {}` into the widgets list for the apos.area on the page. Adding something to the app.js caused the site to break.

Answer (score 0):

I am the lead developer of Apostrophe at P'unk Avenue.

Try `apostrophe-video-widgets`. Works like adding any other widget to an `apos.area` or `apos.singleton` call. There are no required options.

Just as a reminder, when calling `apos.area` or `apos.singleton` you just need the name of the widget (`apostrophe-video`), not the name of the module that happens to provide it (`apostrophe-video-widgets`).

Comment: Thanks Tom! I was able to add the video widget and the text box that shows up only allows the addition of http urls and I am trying to add an iframe youtube url. do I need pass a specific parameter? my code looks like

Comment: {{ apos.area(data.piece, 'main', {
                widgets: {
                  'apostrophe-rich-text': {
                     toolbar: [ 'Styles', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Blockquote', 'Link', 'Anchor', 'Unlink', 'Table', 'BulletedList', 'NumberedList' ],
                   },
                  'apostrophe-video': {
                  }
                }
              }) }}